# Change Receipt Email Title: Template, Localisation File or Somewhere Else?

Tags: civicontribute, localisation

We have a different title for the (pay later) offline receipt contribution email (civiContribute). The first email with the data necessary to make the payment  has a title saying something and the payment confirmation email (sent afterwards) title says something else. I do remember this having been changed by us. However I cannot remember or find where. We would like to change the first email title again, in order to say something else.

I've checked the system workflow message templates and the localisation files at transifex and the change does not seem to have been done there. Is there a translation file for tokens? And if so, where can it be found?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this would be done in the System Workflow message templates - you can change both the message subject and text there, as well as adding more extensive customization using Smarty tags. So it's odd that it's not showing there...

One other option I can think of is that you can change certain pieces of text globally using the Word Replacements feature (Administer > Customize Data & Screens > Word Replacements. So perhaps if there was a word or phrase that you changed not only for the receipt titles but anywhere it was used on the site, you might find it there?